# how to add custom templates in django-ckeditor in django

Tags: python, django, templates, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I am trying to use the **Templates** feature of the CKEditor in Django and I want to add some custom templates in the list. I've used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxTCJasKLYI) approach. I've tried editing

> myvenv\Lib\site-packages\ckeditor\static\ckeditor\ckeditor\plugins\templates\templates\default.js

**default.js**

```
CKEDITOR.addTemplates("default",{imagesPath:CKEDITOR.getUrl(CKEDITOR.plugins.getPath("templates")+"templates/images/"),templates:[{title:"Welcome Template",image:"template2.gif",description:"A template that you can send to clients as a welcome message.",html:' <h2>Welcome</h2> <p>Hi, <strong> Name here </strong> </p><p>You have recently shown an interest . . . </p>'},]});
```

but it didn't help, I've tried the `collect static` command but it didn't help either. I am still seeing the same default three templates.
I'm not sure but there is another option of using extra plugins in the settings.py file but I don't know how to use it for this problem.

**settings.py**

```
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "file_upload/"

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar':'full',
    },
}
```

**apps**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...,
'ckeditor',
'ckeditor_uploader',
]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('ckeditor/',include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),]
```

**models.py**

```
class text(models.Model):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, default="None")
```

So my question is how to add custom templates in `django-ckeditor==6.3.2`?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? (logs, browser network tab, ...)

Comment: not really. Not getting any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this plugin, but from the documentation it seems you're missing an extra step, which is modifying the template location in the HTML template. From the [documentation](https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#required) you can read:

> "sometimes you have to hardcode CKEDITOR_BASEPATH somewhere. It is recommended to override the admin/base_site.html template with your own if you really need to do this, i.e.:"

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
<script>window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/';</script>
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

In that case, make sure the path is accessible from the site. Also, make sure you have added the 'templates' plugin in your CKEditor configuration: [documentation](https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#plugins).

Comment: Thanks, man, adding the plugin explicitly helped me in getting the updated template. Also, I've blocked the cache from saving the data otherwise it was showing old data.

Answer (score -1):

If, by template, you mean to edit toolbar options, you can do it with something like this in your settings.py file.

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default': {
       'toolbar_Full': [
            ['Styles', 'Format', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'SpellChecker', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'],
            ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule'],
            ['TextColor', 'BGColor'],
            ['Smiley', 'SpecialChar'], ['Source'],
            ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
            ['NumberedList','BulletedList'],
            ['Indent','Outdent'],
            ['Maximize'],
        ],
        'extraPlugins': 'justify,liststyle,indent',
   },
}
```

Comment: No, actually there's an option of using templates instead of creating same format again and again in django-ckeditor. I found a way to edit those templates and create your own format. but after editing those templates i am unable to get the changes on the browser. The template file is present at ckeditor/static/templates/plugins/templates/default.js